# Standard Errors in Winsteps: ERROR versus MODLSE

Tags: standard-error

I am running anchored analyses in Winsteps on four data sets (a full data set as well as the data degraded by an additional 20%, 50%, and 70%). I noticed that the standard errors are labeled ERROR for the full data and the data that is degraded an additional 50%, but are labeled MODLSE for the data that is degraded an additional 20% and 70%. This standard error relabeling occurs in both the item file (IFILE) and person file (PFILE) outputs. Does anyone know if ERROR and MODLSE are the same? Why the difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MODLSE and ERROR columns are the same standard error of the estimate. They are obtained from 2 different versions of WINSTEPS. WINSTEPS 3.75 came out right around 10/22/2013, and one of the changes Mike Linacre made was to replace ERROR in the IFILE and PFILE column labels with MODLSE (see #10 under version 3.75 here: http://www.winsteps.com/wingood.htm). It turns out that some of these output files were run on or before 10/22/13 whereas some were run after. Case closed!